# html form two buttons only one to submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, submit

I have a form with two buttons. The save changes button is the submit button but the delete button should not submit once clicked. The delete button should open a modal and in the modal there are two more buttons, one to go back(close modal) and one to finalize the delete. My issue is that as soon as the delete button is clicked on, the form thinks I want to submit which I don't. How could I get around this? Thank you

```
<form>
          <div class="mailing-address">
            <p>Mailing Address</p>
            <div class="form3">
              <span class="edit-mailing1">
                <span>
                  <input type="text" required placeholder="Name" v-model="editFormData.name" />
                  <input type="text" required placeholder="Email" v-model="editFormData.email" />
                </span>
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Address Line 1" v-model="editFormData.address1" />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2" v-model="editFormData.address2" />
              </span>
              <span class="edit-mailing2">
                <input type="text" required placeholder="Phone Number" v-model="editFormData.phone" />
                <input type="text" required placeholder="City" v-model="editFormData.city" />
                <span>
                  <SelectBox v-model="editFormData.state" />
                  <input type="text" required placeholder="Zip" v-model="editFormData.zip" />
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="edit-section-footer">
            <CheckboxSlider v-model="editFormData.vip" :userId="editFormData.id" :reloadTable="reloadTable" />
            <span>
              <button class="button red" @click="isModalOpen = true">Delete User</button>
              <button class="button">Save Changes</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to share the code. I reckon you've probably got a `type="submit"` where it shouldn't be

Comment: May you share the relevant HTML?

Comment: @dbramwell I think all buttons that don’t have type=“button” submit a form as well

Comment: I'll add the html

Comment: I dont see any `<form>` tag. Does this get transpiled via the classes or is this not a *real* html form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `type="submit"` to the submit button, and add `type="button"` to the delete button.

By default, a button inside a form will trigger a submit if there isn't a explicit submit button

Comment: <button class="button red" @click="isModalOpen = true">Delete User</button>
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="save changes" />

This still doesn't change it

Comment: I'll add type="button"

Comment: @albert_anthony6 Try this <button class="button red" @click="isModalOpen = true" type="button">Delete User</button> <input type="submit" class="button" value="save changes" />

Comment: You're correct, just tried it and it worked! Thanks :) I'll mark this as answer when it allows in about 8 mins

Answer (score 1):

to prevent delete button from submit change it type to button insted of submit

```html
<button onclick="somefunction()" type="button">Button</button>
```